# Color coded 2D plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a d<sub>1</sub>×d<sub>2</sub> array `A` of integer values and want to color code display them on the xy-plane in a rectangle scaled to d<sub>1</sub>×d<sub>2</sub> using colors that match the magnitude of the value of array at that location. I also want to display the color chart which indicates which color is which magnitude as in the following figure:-

[image: Fig 3 of http://home.deib.polimi.it/tubaro/Conferences/2013_WASPAA_2.pdf]

Is there a simple code that can do this?

Or is this kind of charting need special packages?

---

Will this work ('A' is matrix with non-negative entries)?

```
function plot2Ddistprf(A, Length, Breadth)

Amax=max(A(:));
A=A/Amax;

G1 = linspace(0,Length,size(A,1));
G2 = linspace(0,Breadth,size(A,2));

[X,Y] = meshgrid(G1,G2);

% plot data
figure;                     % create a new figure
contourf(X,Y,A);            % plot data as surface
caxis([1,100]);            % set limits of colormap
colorbar;                   % display the colorbar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `contourf` function and then add the `colorbar`

```
 contourf(A)
 colorbar
```

Comment: you have a typo: `contourf`

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou what does this do?

Comment: @ClaesRolen do you have an example way to use?

Answer (score 1):

No external library or special package is needed to create such a plot. You can use [`contourf`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html) to plot the data. Then, set the colormap to `gray`. With `caxis` you can control the range of colors. `colorbar` shows the bar on the right side.

*The result looks like this:*

[image: result]

*Here is the code:*

```
% generate sample data
d1 = linspace(-3,3,200);
d2 = linspace(-3,3,200);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(d1,d2);
A = -abs(peaks(X,Y))+100;

% plot data
figure;                     % create a new figure
contourf(X,Y,A);            % plot data as surface

colormap(gray);             % use gray colormap
caxis([91,100]);            % set limits of colormap
colorbar;                   % display the colorbar

title('The Title');
xlabel('y');
ylabel('x');
```

Comment: will this work (A is matrix with non-negative entries)?

function plot2Ddistprf(A, Length, Breadth)
Amax=max(A(:));
A=A/Amax;

G1 = linspace(0,Length,size(A,1));
G2 = linspace(0,Breadth,size(A,2));
%d2 = linspace(-3,3,200);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(G1,G2);

% plot data
figure;                     % create a new figure
contourf(X,Y,A);            % plot data as surface

caxis([1,100]);            % set limits of colormap
colorbar;                   % display the colorbar

title('The Title');
xlabel('y');
ylabel('x');

Comment: how will you scale for color data?

Comment: @Turbo try it instead of asking!

Comment: @Turbo This is basically what I wrote in my answer, so yes it will work, depending on what you want to achieve. The color can be scaled with the values in `caxis`. If you normalize them, you can for example use `caxis([0,1])`. Have a look [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) for other colormaps that you could use because one with only a single color probably looks much better.